# Gnu make conditional on environment variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following in a Makefile:

```
ifndef MYVAR
$(error "MYVAR is not set")
else
$(warning "MYVAR is set to [$(MYVAR)]")
ifeq ($(MYVAR),"abc")
$(error "Value is known.")
else
$(error "Not known.")
endif
endif
```

I set MYVAR when calling make:

```
MYVAR=abc make
```

I would have expected to see "Value is known." but I get the following:

```
Makefile:4: "MYVAR is set to [abc]"
Makefile:8: *** "Not known.".  Stop.
```

Could someone please enlighten me on what is wrong with my ifeq statement?

Comment: `ifeq ($(MYVAR),abc)` or `MYVAR='"abc"' make`.

Comment: Doh! Thank you, @melpomene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question answered by @melpomene in the comments. As so often before, a quotation error.

```
ifeq ($(MYVAR),abc) or MYVAR='"abc"' make
```